# Where can I find a list of the sites I've +1'ed?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

If I go to my Google dashboard I can see the most recent +1 I made (below), but where can I find all the other websites/pages I've +1'ed?

[image: Google+ in my dashboard]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the new Google+ pages,

> You can go back and see posts and comments you've +1ed by [checking your Activity Log](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6320418#activitylog). You can also remove your +1 using the Activity Log.

To do that, go to *Settings* and click on the **[Activity Log](https://plus.google.com/apps/activities)** link.

[image]

From there, you can see all your +1.

[image]

---

> If you want to see posts you’ve +1’d on Google+, check out your [Activity log](https://plus.google.com/apps/activities). If you want to see the things you’ve +1’d outside of Google+, you can visit the +1s tab on your Google+ profile.
>
> #### Computer
>
> 1. Open [Google+](https://plus.google.com/).
> 2. Near the top left corner, click the drop-down arrow [image] > **Profile**.
> 3. Under your cover photo, click the **+1’s** tab.
>
> #### Android app / Mobile browser / iPhone/iPad app
>
> You can’t see your +1s on a mobile device just yet. Please check out the +1s tab from a computer.

[Source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047397?hl=en).

---

> You'll find your full list of +1's in a special tab on your public Google profile.

From [here](http://www.google.com/+1/button/).

So basically, go to your Google+ profile and click on **+1's**

[image]

Comment: Thank you - those pesky "tabs" that just look like text bug me. Their whole UI is designed as if there are no buttons or click regions. It's just horrible IMO.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this for business pages?  See what my page has +1'ed?

Comment: In G+ new page design, the **Settings page** https://plus.google.com/settings gives a link to **Activity Log** https://plus.google.com/apps/activities that allows you to view all activities like "Posts", "Comments", "+1's on posts", "+1's on comments", "+1's on sites" etc.