# Google+ +1 tab missing - where do I find what pages I have given +1?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

I want to know what pages I have given a +1 in Google+.

Previously I could see this in the +1 tab on my Google+ profile.
[The help still describes this as the place to look](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047397?hl=en)

However, I can no longer find any +1 tab on my Google+ profile. It now just displays my "interests" and my posts. I cannot find any complete list of the pages that I have given +1.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that that information is no longer accessible through a link on Google+ since the recent redesign.

In order to view your previous "+1's" through a link, you'll have to go **Back to classic G+**. You'll find a link in the lower left on the menu, which will take you back to your old-style profile which will show **+1's** as a menu item.

You can also go directly to your +1's through this link: https://plus.google.com/me/plusones (you'll need to be logged in)

How long either of these remains available is unknown.

Comment: The questioner did ask about pages. However I note that https://plus.google.com/me/plusones only shows pages you +1. It excludes G+ posts that you +1.

Comment: [Where can I find a list of the sites I've +1'ed?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18585/354)

Comment: _"How long either of these remains available is unknown."_ this should be written in bold with bigger characters.

Comment: as of today, this link is already broken to me. the one from @ethan's answer, however, work! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also find your +1 activity in your activity log: https://plus.google.com/apps/activities

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Good alternative. There is a specific page to see your **+1s on sites** (or pages)
https://plus.google.com/apps/activities/plus_one_web .

I just noticed (after looking for it) that the plus settings page gives a link to **activity log**
https://plus.google.com/settings